# MahApps ToggleSwitch not found in version 2.0 in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro, .net-core-3.1

I am using the latest version of MahApps.Metro for a wpf-mvvm netcoreapp3.1 app. I migrated the mvvm app over from a wpf-mvvm .netframework4.7 app. I previously had the following for the wpf-mvvm .netframework4.7 app:

```
 <mahapps:ToggleSwitch  OnLabel="{Binding OnLabelText}" 
                        OffLabel="{Binding OffLabelText}"
                        CheckedCommand="{Binding StartDistributionCommand}"
                        UnCheckedCommand="{Binding StopDistributionCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding WebDistributionOnStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The updated version for wpf .netcoreapp3.1 is:

```
 <mahapps:ToggleSwitch  OnContent="{Binding OnLabelText}" 
                        OffContent="{Binding OffLabelText}"
                        CheckedCommand="{Binding StartDistributionCommand}"
                        UnCheckedCommand="{Binding StopDistributionCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
                        IsOn="{Binding WebDistributionOnStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The problem is the **CheckedCommand** and **UnCheckedCommand** parameters no longer exist for the ToggleSwitch Control and I cannot find a suitable replacement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved thanks to @punker76 for adding two properties to [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) in pull-request [#3785](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/3785)

```
<Controls:ToggleSwitch CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                   OnCommand="{Binding ToggleSwitchOnCommand}"
                   OffCommand="{Binding ToggleSwitchOffCommand}" />
```